# NPN BJT Vbe & Vce Using one ground?

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

Is it true that  +5v & +12v can not share the -12v ground on a NPN BJT being used as a switch controlled by a MCU signal? If so why?
[image]

Comment: you mean to say 12V Return (-) was floating but now shares 5V Return (-) as a common ground. This is normal. It is also normal to include a current limiting base Resistor such that Ib=Ic/k for k=10 to 20 and not hFE to reach Vce(sat) for low loss.

Answer (score 1):

First you need proper resistor at the base and collector to limit current flowing through the device are else you will make permanent damage to the device

I am assuming the circuit you had put in is for functional purpose

From the circuit, you are using the NPN transistor as switch, to make it ON you need to forward bias the Base Emitter junction and to OFF you need to bring down the voltage below the base emitter junction voltage, now check if the two things are possible with your setup

To make the transistor OFF you need to apply a voltage -12v - 0.7 (assuming nominal base emitter voltage 0.7V) you need to apply minimum -12.7 V so it is not possible with your MCU, so with your circuit the switch is always on